# why is the plural form of sheep is not sheeps?

Tags: plural-forms, etymology

The plural of *goat* is *goats*. Even uncountable nouns can have plural forms, e.g. waters (the meaning is slightly different). Some words have two plural forms, like cactuses or cacti. Again, some words have altogether a different form, like bevy.

Dynamism and flexibility are unique characteristics of the English language. But, '*sheeps*' and *'deers'* are not used. I fail to understand the logic behind that.

I would like to delve a little deeper into the *etymology* of these words. So, why is '*sheeps*,' or *'deers'* not approved as the plural forms? Why are they exceptional?

Comment: Google **why sheep and not sheeps**

Comment: *Why does English do aribitrary thing X* type questions like this might be a better for for english.stackexchange.com.  I found this on ELU -- one of the answers might lead to something interesting that could explain it: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279563/can-the-plural-form-of-sheep-ever-be-sheeps

Comment: https://blog.oup.com/2017/10/etymology-sheep-word-origins/#:~:text=The%20Old%20English%20form%20of,one%20sheep%20~%20many%20sheep%20today. might be helpful. I would've answered but I can't explain it because I'll need to do some research and will have to study Old English grammar.... and I'm not interested in grammar :)

Comment: Here you go: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50309/why-is-sheep-the-same-when-talking-about-one-or-more-than-one

Comment: While some trace the explanation to the particular Old English declension (whose nom. and acc. forms were the same in the plural as in the singular), that can only ever be a small part of the explanation.  For example, "land" also derives from an OE neuter that was identical in its nominative and accusative plural to its nominative and accusative singular.  Doesn't stop us saying "lands" today, does it?

Comment: see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45039/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-identical-singular-and-plural-forms

Comment: My (totally unsupported) guess is that “sheep” is already plural, like “feet”, “teeth” or “geese”, and what got lost is the singular “shoop”, like “foot”, “tooth” or “goose”, because they didn’t talk about one shoop often enough for the word to stay in use.

Comment: I've added an answer to the existing question at the ELU se (as per Micah Windsor's link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50309/why-is-sheep-the-same-when-talking-about-one-or-more-than-one ).